# Python with openCV on MAC crashes

Tags: eclipse, macos, opencv, python-2.7, pydev

My final goal is to use Python scripts with SciPy, NumPy, Theano and openCV libraries to write code for a machine learning application. Everything worked so far apart from the openCV.

I am trying to install openCV 2.4.8 to use in Python projects in my Eclipse Kepler installation on my MBA running Mac OSX 10.9.2. I have the PyDef plugin v2.7 and a installation of Anaconda v1.9.1.

Here is what I did to install opencv:

> sudo port selfupdate
>
> sudo port upgrade outdated
>
> sudo port install opencv

Then I realized that I can't use it that way in Python and did another:

> sudo port install opencv +python27

Ok, then I had another Python installation and I added it to my PYTHONPATH in Eclipse>Preferences>PyDev>Interpreter-Python>Libraries.

Before the installation I got an error in the line `import cv2`, and everything else looked promising. Now this error disappeared but I get other errors when using any functions or variables of cv2. For example  I get two errors in this line: `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`

Also Python crashes and has to be restarted when I run a simple test program which worked fine before.

With this PYTHONPATH everything works but I have no openCV:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyObjC
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
> /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

When I add this new folder to the PYTHONPATH...

> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

... openCV seems to work but I have the crashes and the other issue described above.

So, can anyone tell me what the problem is and what I can do to make this work?

Thanks for reading this so far and any help/hint you can provide! Please don't be too harsh, I am, as you can probably easily see just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's working now. Here is what I did:

1. Install Python and every package I need for it with Macports
2. Set the Macports version as standard
3. Adjust PATH and PYTHONPATH
4. Reboot (not sure if needed)
5. Remove old interpreter and libs in Eclipse
6. Choose the new Python installation as Interpreter in Eclipse
7. Confirm the new libs in Eclipse
8. Restart Eclipse
9. Done